# Restoring nuget package from private nuget feed - Docker gives an error

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a docker image but it gives this error when trying to restore a Nuget package from private Nuget Feed.I have tried many solutions from all over the internet.Nothing ha worked so far.Pls help.

My Docker File looks like this: -

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Api/Api.csproj", "Api/"]
COPY ["Persistence.EntityFramework/Nuget.config", "Persistence.EntityFramework/"]
COPY ["Contracts/Contracts.csproj", "Contracts/"]
COPY ["Persistence/Persistence.csproj", "Persistence/"]
COPY ["Domain/Domain.csproj", "Domain/"]
COPY ["Handlers/Handlers.csproj", "Handlers/"]
COPY ["Localisation/Localisation.csproj", "Localisation/"]
COPY ["Persistence.EntityFramework/Persistence.EntityFramework.csproj", "Persistence.EntityFramework/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Persistence.EntityFramework/Persistence.EntityFramework.csproj" --configfile "Persistence.EntityFramework/Nuget.config"
RUN dotnet restore "Api/Api.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Api"
RUN dotnet build "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Security.Api.dll"]
```

My Nuget.Config looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="companyname" value="http://vnuget.companyname.com/privateNugetFeed/nuget/Packages"/>    
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

This is the error we see:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://vnuget.companyname.com/privateNugetFeed/nuget/Packages/FindPackagesById()?id='Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
[15:44:36][Step 3/7]   Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi I have found the problem ..

The Package Source link in my Nuget config file is incorrect

It should be :-

```
 <add key="companyname" value="http://vnuget.companyname.com/privateNugetFeed/nuget"/>
```

This has resolved the issue and docker is building correctly now!Voila